# Can I exponentiate the log-Bayes factor to get the Bayes factor?

Tags: bayes-factors

Simple question here. I'm using Bayesian Confirmatory Factor Analysis and I can get a log-Bayes Factor with the Laplace approximation. However, I'm wondering whether I can just exponentiate this value and get the "normal" Bayes factor?

Thanks for any help!

Cheers,
Pedro

Comment: The direct answer is yes you can!, the indirect one is what you expect or fear from using the exponential transform.

Comment: Hi Xi'an, thanks so much for the comment! I'm converting to the "normal" Bayes Factor because for me the interpretation is more straightforward compared to the log-Bayes factor :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

Though careful about interpreting the uncertainties on the Bayes factor itself. It's not common that the errors on estiamtes of log evidences and thus log Bayes factors are symmetric and roughly normal, thus leading to skewed, asymmetric uncertainties on the evidences or Bayes factor.

Though in any case, often we only care about the order of magnitude of the Bayes factor. See e.g., Jeffreys' famous (logarithmic) scale for ascribing qualitative meanings to Bayes factors of different magnitudes.